# friendly urls with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following .htaccess code in my website to redirect all the urls to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

then I am checking the url and see if the name of the page is available in the database. Then I am redirecting the user the that specific page if it is found like so:

```
www.mywebsite.com/videos.php?v=Name_of_the_video
www.mywebsite.com/images.php?i=Name_of_the_image
www.mywebsite.com/users.php?u=Name_of_the_user
```

as you can see I have 3 main types of pages. I want to use .htacces so I can convert those urls like so:

```
www.mywebsite.com/videos/Name_of_the_video
www.mywebsite.com/images/Name_of_the_image
www.mywebsite.com/users/Name_of_the_user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/])([^/]+)/(.*) /$1$2.php?$1=$3 [L,QSA]
```

You'll probably want to put this before your other rules though.